# Moving local SVN repo, but keeping it local

Tags: svn, version-control

I created a local SVN repo (called, simply enough, `svnrep`) to learn version control the Subversion way. I'm cleaning up my folder structure and I want to move the repo, while keeping it local. I have just one project (named, simply enough, `project1`), and it is checked out.

I want to 1) delete the checked out version of `project1`; 2) delete `project1` inside `svnrep`; and 3) move `svnrep` from one directory to another.

From searching on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, I gather that I will be using `svn export` and `svnadmin dump`, but I am nervous moving forward without explicit instructions that match my situation. I'd be very grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's local, no need:

1. Move the repo to the desired location (just move the directory, no fancy stuff needed)
2. Point your checkout to that location with `svn switch --relocate oldpath TO newpath`.